# Hibernate Envers - Adding Historical Data

Tags: hibernate-envers

Is there a way to add revision straight into the _AUD tables as a historical revision?

As I understand it as and when an entity is persisted envers creates a revision record in the _AUD table and keeping the current record in the entity table. Suppose I would like to add historical revision and not affect the entity table, is this possible?

For example, I have a Person entity

```
PERSON
ID | NAME 
1  | SMITH

PERSON_AUD
ID | REV | REVTYPE | NAME
1  | 1   | 0       | SMITH
```

I would like to add the following in PERSON_AUD without modifying the PERSON table as SMITH is the current name.

```
PERSON_AUD
ID | REV | REVTYPE | NAME
1  | 1   | 0       | SMITH
1  | 2   | 2       | JONES
```

Comment: Revtype on the second revision should be 1 for modification.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that's not possible with the current Envers API.

Comment: Hi Adam - I've been looking at ValidityAuditStrategy and can see this class is responsible for providing the value for REVEND_TSTMP column when a new revision is created. I can extend this class to provide values for other columns to be updated from the previous revision like the REVEND_TSTMP. 

It would be good to be able to have extension points to achieve this, do you think something like this would be in future releases?

Comment: Well the VAS does also some other things, mostly concerned with actually writing the new revision entity entry. If you would want to add such a feature, probably it would make more sense to create an AuditWriter, but I'm not sure if more people would be interested in that.

Comment: For our current implementation it would a very useful feature to have a Listener fired like the RevisionListner but one where the previous revinfo is provided. This will give us an extension point to update the previous revinfo.

Answer (score 0):

My background is C# but since the frameworks for Java are more powerful (at least I think this) I am sure you will find the related methods.

1) Reattaching the entity to the session will create a new revision:

```
private void Reattach(Person person)
{
    _sessionContainer.Session.Transaction.Begin();
    _sessionContainer.Session.Evict(person);
    _sessionContainer.Session.Update(person);
    _sessionContainer.Session.Flush();
    _sessionContainer.Session.Transaction.Commit();
}
```

2) If you want to manipiulate the audit entry you need to append a listener (in this case for preupdate):

```
configuration.AppendListeners(ListenerType.PreUpdate, new object[] { new PreUpdateListener() });
```

where the implementation is doing the magic:

```
public class PreUpdateListener : IPreUpdateEventListener
{
    public bool OnPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent ev)
    {
        var person = ev.Entity as Person;
        if (person != null)
        {
            person.Name = "Jones";
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Please let me know if this approach is working for you.

Comment: Hi Rico - I am actually evaluating Hibernate+Envers with Spring JPA and don't really want to go off from the out of the box features this early in the evaluation process. And having done a little big of digging around I think it'll be easier to just have service with a Jdbc writing sql and inserting the audit records.

Answer (score -1):

You seem to be forgetting or not aware of the fact that revision number is global; it is tracked in a separate table which is called `REVINFO` in the default setup. Each entry for a revision number is accompanied by a timestamp as well. It is simply wrong (might even become a serious situation depending on the environment) to be inserting historical data that wasn't created naturally.

If you still want to do this, you can use native SQL to do it by creating a revision entry in REVINFO first and then using that in your audit table. Which is wrong.